# AWK to help solve Wordle puzzles

Tags: awk, games

I have seen several [articles](https://opensource.com/article/22/1/word-game-linux-command-line) describing how basic Linux commands (grep and regex) can solve Wordle puzzles. If you are not familiar with the game check the notes at the end of this question. I decided to use awk for this purpose. Here is my first attempt:

```
awk 'length($0)==5' /usr/share/dict/words | awk '!/\-|\x27|[A-Z]/'  | awk '!/[isbou]/' | awk '/a/&&/l/&&/e/&&/e/&&/t/'  | awk '/...a/' | cat -n
```

The first two awk's produce the list of 5-letter words (and exclude uppercase words, hyphens, apostrophe) from the dictionary in the standard Ubuntu installation.

```
awk '/a/&&/l/&&/e/&&/t/'
```

(for yellow letters)
filters in those words with letters present -- in the word but not in the write place. in this example letters a,l,e,t

```
awk '!/[isbou]/'
```

(for grey letters)
filters out words that include any of these letters -- in this example i,s,b,o,u

```
awk '/...a/'
```

(for green letters)
for letters that are present and in the correct position.

I decided to use a list of 5-letter words as my dictionary to keep the code simple. You can prepare such a list in various ways. For example:

```
awk 'length($0)==5' /usr/share/dict/words | awk '!/\-|\x27|[A-Z]/' > fives.txt
```

or

```
curl -s 'https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=100000' | awk -v RS=',' '{gsub(/[]["]+/,"")}1' | awk 'length($i)==5' > fives.txt
```

Placing this file (fives.txt) in the home directory, the command becomes much shorter:

```
cat ~/fives.txt | awk '!/[isbou]/' | awk '/a/&&/l/&&/e/&&/e/&&/t/'  | awk '/...a/' | cat -n
```

This works well. But can this be shortened? how can the check for yellow letters be made more elegant and less susceptible to typing errors when editing the command for the next guess?

Note: The rules are very simple: You need to guess the hidden word (normally 5) in 6 tries. To get started, just type any word on the first line. If the letter is guessed correctly and is in the correct place, it will be highlighted in green, if the letter is in the word, but in the wrong place - in yellow, and if the letter is not in the word, it will remain grey. Can you guess the hidden word in 6 tries?

Comment: What's the point of `awk '!/[isbou]/'`? You already have just 5-letter words so if `/a/&&/l/&&/e/&&/e/&&/t/` is true, then by definition they can't match `[isbou]`.

Comment: 1) this `awk '/[:alpha:]/'` doesn't exclude hyphen `-` and apostrophe `'` as you think, it only prints words that have at least a single alphabet character, so things like `'''a-` for example will be included in your output; 2) this `awk '/...a/'` doesn't actually check the correct position, it only checks if there is an `a` character followed by 3other characters;

Comment: You are quite right Afshin on both account. What are the correct code segments for them?

Comment: you have already received some answers below

Comment: In case it's useful to any others who also don't have /usr/share/dict/words on their system: to get 100K random words at a time I use `curl -s 'https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=100000' | awk -v RS=',' '{gsub(/[]["]+/,"")}1'` on any system.

Comment: The code is only an aid to narrow down the options to just a few words. Ultimately the solution is a guess work.I have amended the tile.

Comment: So is the purpose of this question just to write `awk 'length($0)==5' /usr/share/dict/words | awk '!/[A-Z]/' | awk '/[:alpha:]/' | awk '!/[isbou]/' | awk '/a/&&/l/&&/e/&&/e/&&/t/'  | awk '/...a/' | cat -n` more concisely or something else?

Comment: You got it. I have to edit and re-use this command after every guess.

Comment: You're refering to 3 different input sources (`/usr/share/dict/words`, `aspell`, and `fives.txt`) at different points in the question and I don't think you'd need the same script for each but idk which is adding to my confusion. I provided an answer if `words` is your input but I see others have provided different answers for `fives.txt`. A single input source used throughout the question along with some sample input (from that source) and expected output would be useful.

Comment: I assumed that /usr/share/dict/words that comes as standard Ubuntu package is related to aspell command. Turns out that this dictionary is not very comprehensive anyway. For example the number of five letter words in it is around 4000. Whereas the fives.txt contains nearly 14000 words.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten this by combining all the AWK filters and merging the `cat` features:

```
awk '!/[isbou]/ && /a/&&/l/&&/e/&&/t/ && /^...a.$/ { printf("%6d %s\n", ++i, $0) }' ~/fives.txt
```

I fixed the green filter to specifically check for the five positions.

Instead of trying to simplify the AWK part further, I would use a shell script with three arguments: the list of gray letters, the list of yellow letters, and the green letters in the right position.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

awkcmd=""

if [[ ${#1} -gt 0 ]]; then
    awkcmd="${awkcmd}!/[$1]/ &&"
fi

if [[ ${#2} -gt 0 ]]; then
    for (( i=0; i < ${#2}; i++ )); do
    awkcmd="${awkcmd} /${2:$i:1}/ &&"
    done
fi

if [[ ${#3} -gt 0 ]]; then
    awkcmd="${awkcmd} /$3/"
else
    awkcmd="${awkcmd} 1"
fi

awkcmd="${awkcmd} { printf(\"%6d %s\n\", ++i, \$0) }"

awk "$awkcmd" ~/fives.txt
```

With a more general word list, use `awkcmd="/^[a-z]{5}$/ &&"` in line 3.

Comment: Stephen I like your oneliner but in the green letters segment /^...a.$/ I get the same results with /...a./ so is there a point in using ^ and $ to define start and end of the string? You can try it yourself.

Comment: @elmclose with a five-letter wordlist it won’t make any difference, but it makes it clear that you want to match the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

A very crude script (more like a stub) could start out something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
conditions='/^[a-z]{5}$/'

while getopts "c:i:e:" opt; do case "${opt}" in
    c) conditions+=" && /^${OPTARG,,}/" ;;
    i) conditions+=$(sed 's|.| \&\& /&/|g' <<<"${OPTARG,,}") ;;
    e) conditions+=" && !/[${OPTARG,,}]/" ;;
esac; done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

awk "${conditions} { print toupper(\$0) }" /usr/share/dict/words
```

Calling `./wordle.sh -c "...a" -i "alet" -e "isbou"` would yield:

```
CLEAT
FETAL
METAL
PETAL
PLEAT
```

The awk it generates in this example would be:

```bsh
awk '/^[a-z]{5}$/ && /^...a/ && /a/ && /l/ && /e/ && /t/ && !/[isbou]/ { print toupper($0) }' /usr/share/dict/words
```

... and the sloppy call for the script would be `./wordle.sh -c...a -ialet -eisbou`

Of course, the `{ print toupper(\$0) }` part of the script is entirely cosmetic and can be removed. It was added as Wordle has chosen to only use capital letters in the gui. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in excluding anything since you already have only 5-letter words, so the `!/[isbou]/` is pointless if you are then checking for `/a/&&/l/&&/e/&&/e/&&/t/`. Next, the repeated `/e/ && /e/` is pointless, that doesn't check for two `e`s, it only checks for one but checks for the same thing twice. If you want to find cases with two `e`'s, you want `/e.*e/`. So, putting all this together, this might be what you want:

```
awk '/...a./ && /l/ &&/e.*e/ && /t/{print ++k,$0}' ~/fives.txt
```

Comment: `print NR` isn’t equivalent to `cat -n` – `NR` is the line number in the unfiltered list, whereas `cat -n` numbers the lines in the output. The doubled “e” in the question is a mistake, there is no five-letter word matching the constraints with two “e”s. `!/[isbou]/` excludes four words containing “a”, “l”, “e” and “t”.

Comment: @StephenKitt thanks, fixed the NR, good point! Mistake or not, that's what the OP was looking for (they might be working in another language?). And yes, I know what the `!/[isbou]/` does, but it is pointless when used in combination with `/a/ && /l/ &&/e.*e/ && /t/` on five-letter input. If a five-character string matches `a`, and `l` and `e.*e` and `t`, then it cannot match any of `i`, `s`, `b`, `o` or `u`.

Comment: My point is that “e” is only doubled in the last command; previous commands and descriptions only mention one. That’s why I think that the repetition in the last command is accidental.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write this:

```
awk 'length($0)==5' /usr/share/dict/words | awk '!/[A-Z]/' | awk '/[:alpha:]/' | awk '!/[isbou]/' | awk '/a/&&/l/&&/e/&&/e/&&/t/'  | awk '/...a/' | cat -n
```

more concisely, it'd be:

```
awk '!/[A-Zisbou]/ && /l/&&/e/&&/t/ && /^...a.$/ {print ++n, $0}' /usr/share/dict/words
```

but if you want to exclude "words" that contain characters that aren't lower case alphabetic that'd be:

```
awk '/^[[:lower:]]+$/ && /l/&&/e/&&/t/ && /^...a.$/ {print ++n, $0}' /usr/share/dict/words
```

or if you prefer:

```
awk '/l/&&/e/&&/t/ && /^[[:lower:]]{3}a[[:lower:]]$/ {print ++n, $0}' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Ideally we need to exclude words with hyphens and apostrophes. I don't know how to do that. The segment in my code \[:alpha:]\ won't do it and must change.

Comment: You're welcome. You should add that requirement to your question and include such undesirable words in your to-be-provided sample input.